# Count Similar Substrings SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've tried a few scenarios and googled a lot, but still can't find a solution.

I have a table of user names with entries something like the below:

| UserName |
| --- |
| Cakes420 |
| 18Jack01 |
| 18Jack04 |
| 16Jack22 |
| 22Jack16 |
| Mapple7609 |
| Chrom44 |
| chrom22 |
| chrom77 |
| 013Cake |
| 016Cake |
| 122Cake |
| 123Cake87 |

So I need a query that checks for all records that share 4 or more (in sequence) characters in the table.

So I need to return something like :

| Characters | Times Used | Names Sharing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cake | 5 | Cakes420, 013Cake, 016Cake, 122Cake, 123Cake87 |
| Chro | 3 | Chrom44, chrom22, chrom77 |

or anything similar as I'd prefer not to repeat patterns, but hey, at this stage if it returns the values properly, I don't mind.

The shared characters can naturally appear in any place in the string, which is what makes this so difficult.

Comment: SQL is not really a suitable tool for this.

Comment: Are the 4 or more shared characters be provided on the query? or you want sql to inspect all data matching the x amount of characters itself?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions here in C# maybe as well, and it needs to inspect it , due to the nature that it can be any combination anywhere in the name

Comment: Can you explain what the end goal should be? maybe we can recommend another way of doing it if we see the full picture

Comment: What does "share 4 or more characters" really mean? For example, "Julissa DC" and "Quinell Sturthers" "share 4 or more characters" (`'u'`, `'l'`, `'i'`, `' '`, and `'s'`), should that be flagged? I wouldn't same the names are similar at all though.

Comment: No, so basically it will be 4 characters in sequence, so Quinell and Quinton will share Quin, but Julissa wont be included with these 2,

Comment: `SOUNDEX()` might help a little, but SQL really not the place for this. Maybe a CLR function?

Comment: @Charlieface what would the CLR look lik then?

Comment: Just thinking: I have a solution based on n-grams. How long is the width of the column (varchar length), I need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use [Itzik Ben-Gan's Tally Function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) to break out a list of substrings, then group them. This is called `N-Gram`, after the more common `Trigram` which is 3-character substrings.

I've removed one extra cross-join from the function to speed it up slightly, it's now good for up to `varchar(65536)`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@num AS BIGINT)
  RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
 
  WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L2 )
  SELECT TOP(@num)
     rownum AS rn
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO


DECLARE @substringLen int = 4;
SELECT
    Characters,
    [Times Used] = COUNT(*),
    [Names Sharing] = STRING_AGG(Username, ', ')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
-- remove DISTINCT if you want to know about multiple in a single username
        t.Username,
        Characters = SUBSTRING(t.Username, n.rn, @substringLen)
    FROM myTable t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNums (LEN(t.UserName) - @substringLen + 1) n
) t
GROUP BY t.Characters
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

*Should* you do this in T-SQL? Probably not.
*Can* you do this in T-SQL? Yes.

**Sample data**

```
create table Names
(
  Name nvarchar(20)
);

insert into Names (Name) values
('Cakes420'),
('18Jack01'),
('18Jack04'),
('16Jack22'),
('22Jack16'),
('Mapple7609'),
('Chrom44'),
('chrom22'),
('chrom77'),
('013Cake'),
('016Cake'),
('122Cake'),
('123Cake87');
```

**Solution**

Using [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) for easy concatenation. Available from SQL Server 2017. Alternatives available for older SQL versions (use the search box on this site, there are many examples).

```
with rcte as
(
  select n.Name,
         convert(nvarchar(4), substring(n.Name, 1, 4)) as Part,
         1 as PartFrom
  from Names n
  where len(n.Name) >= 4
    union all
  select r.Name,
         convert(nvarchar(4), substring(r.Name, r.PartFrom+1, r.PartFrom+4)),
         r.PartFrom+1
  from rcte r
  where len(r.Name) >= r.PartFrom+4
),
cte_count as
(
  select r.Part,
         count(1) as PartCount
  from rcte r
  where r.Part not like '%[0-9]%' -- exclude parts with numbers in them
  group by r.Part
  having count(1) > 1
)
select c.Part,
       c.PartCount,
       string_agg(r.Name, ', ') as Names
from cte_count c
join rcte r
  on r.Part = c.Part
group by c.Part,
         c.PartCount
order by c.Part;
```

**Result**

```
Part PartCount Names
---- --------- ----------------------------------------------
Cake 5         Cakes420, 123Cake87, 122Cake, 016Cake, 013Cake
Chro 3         Chrom44, chrom22, chrom77
hrom 3         chrom77, chrom22, Chrom44
Jack 4         22Jack16, 16Jack22, 18Jack04, 18Jack01
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d60909100ee6ce3b35b9c66bca56a82b) to see it in action with the intermediate CTE results.

Comment: rCTE is going to be dog slow. Use a proper tally function

Comment: I never claimed that my solution was ultra performant, nor was it an explicit requirement in the question. At least mine works and does not contain errors, [like yours](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f0e4d05cd00589e0ca9e495d2b88b5e).

Comment: Sorry fixed. It was more on the whole principle of doing a rCTE for this, I guess my code "muscle memory" tells me straight away to use the tally function rather than rCTE (there's almost never a reason not to), so I commented.

Comment: Happy to see another working solution, now OP can choose :-) I am familiar with tally tables, but I probably use them less than I could. If performance is an issue (and when is it not), then your solution is probably preferred.